# Why is Good Friday not called Black Friday?

Tags: crucifixion, good-and-evil, good-friday

It make more sense to me that Black Friday should be Good Friday`s name,it would indicate the darkness that over took the earth BETTER!

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). This sounds more like a statement than a question. Was there something you wanted to know about the beliefs of a particular Christian denomination? See: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: The. Entire redemption of mankind is based on the death of Jesus            The good his sacrifice accomplishes began upon his death

Answer (score 0):

In the past Good Friday has been called Black Friday in some regions because of the [black vestments](https://books.google.ca/books?id=pz2ORay2HWoC&pg=RA1-PA639&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) that were once employed by the clergy on this day.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good_Friday) has this to say about Good Friday:

> Good Friday is a Christian holiday commemorating the crucifixion of Jesus Christ and his death at Calvary. It is observed during Holy Week as part of the Paschal Triduum on the Friday preceding Easter Sunday, and may coincide with the Jewish observance of Passover. It is also known as Holy Friday, Great Friday, [Black Friday](https://books.google.ca/books?id=fSRHbo_RfLoC&pg=PA226&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false).